# count of words in a string from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a word list and I need to find the count of words that are present in the string.

eg:

```
text_string = 'I came, I saw, I conquered!'
word_list=['I','saw','Britain']
```

I require a python script that prints

```
{‘i’:3,’saw’:1,’britain':0}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are expected to show that you have at least made some effort to find a solution yourself. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this: text_string = 'I am a British'
print(word_distribution(text_string,word_list=['I','saw','India']))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` to find all the words in `text_string`, then use `collections.Counter` to produce a dict of words with their counts, and use dict comprehension to produce a dict based on words in the `word_list` and their corresponding counts in the dict produced by `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
c = Counter(re.findall(r'[a-z]+', text_string.lower()))
print({w: c.get(w, 0) for w in map(str.lower, word_list)})
```

This outputs:

```
{'i': 3, 'saw': 1, 'britain': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
text_string = 'I came, I saw, I conquered!'
word_list=['I','saw','Britain']
text_string = text_string.lower()

print(dict((i, text_string.count(i)) for i in map(str.lower, word_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
{'i': 3, 'britain': 0, 'saw': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension here

```
d = {i.lower(): text_string.count(i) for i in word_list}
```

> ```
> :~/python/stack$ python3.7 sum.py 
> {'i': 3, 'saw': 1, 'britain': 0}
> ```

Full loop explained:

```
d = {}
for i in word_list:
    d[i.lower()] = text_string.count(i)
```